# How to get current logged in user id in process builder

Tags: process-builder, platform-event

I am creating a process builder that will publish an event using platform events. I want the process builder to publish an event only when:
The currently logged in user has the same ID as one of the fields in my custom object (Client) AND when a specific checkbox is ticked in the custome object (Client).

How would I be able to get the current logged in user's ID and check if it matches a field in the client object?

Comment: `$User.Id ` would return the current user id.

Comment: And would I put that under formula ?

Comment: Absolutely. In the formula section there is a drop down for System Variables, you can configure system variables from there.

Comment: Might want to format it as an answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

In the formula section there is a drop down for **System Variables**, you can configure system variables from there.

For current logged in user id use `$User.id`.